# Fail to play sequence of MP4 videos across trials

Tags: python, for-loop, video, psychopy, trial

I have 10 trials and two conditions (randomized across the trials) that consist of playing either an optic flow mp4 movie or a random flow mp4 movie. To load and play the mp4 I used visual.MovieStim3

```
nBlocks = 4
nTrials = 10

nb_conditions = np.arange(1,3) # We have two conditions : condition 1 is Optic flow and condition 2 is Random flow

conditions = nb_conditions.repeat(nTrials/2) # 5 times condition1 and 5 times condition2

conditions_rand = np.random.permutation(nb_conditions) # Randomize the order of the conditions

# --- Load optic flow and random flow movies ---

optic_flow_movie = visual.MovieStim3(win, ‘optic_flow.mp4’)
random_flow_movie = visual.MovieStim3(win, ‘random_flow.mp4’)

# --- iterate through trials and play movies---

for trialcount in range(nTrials):

   for Nframes in range(700):

       if conditions_rand[trialcount] == 1:
           optic_flow_movie.draw()


       elif conditions_rand[trialcount] == 2:
           random_flow_movie.draw()

       win.flip()
win.close()
```

It starts playing the first video on the conditions_rand array, then at a random interval of time, it shows a second video and then the screen is black again for a long time as it freezes. Because it doesn’t throw any error, I have no idea why it is behaving this way. Your help would be highly appreciated thanks !!

Comment: Your code looks good - unfortunately these movie playing performance issues are often something to do with interactions between OS/graphics card/which version of the `MovieStim` class you are using. A similar issue has been reported on the support forum here: https://discourse.psychopy.org/t/moviestim3-timing-issues-with-frame-by-frame-presentation/5393 I think a solution was to re-instantiate the movies before each play, but in your case, that would introduce a timing glitch, as you need the movies to instantly alternate from one to the other. Might be worth posting this on that forum

Comment: Also for performance issues, it is important that the pixel-dimensions of the video are no larger than that of the window on which it is being played, as otherwise it is just wasting memory and processing cycles. That probably isn't the case, but just thought I'd check.

Comment: Lastly, just one possible coding suggestion: insert `optic_flow_movie.seek(0)` and `random_flow_movie.seek(0)` in between the two `for` loops, so the movies get re-set to their start frame before getting played again.

Comment: @MichaelMacAskill Putting the two suggested line between the for loops fixed the problem, thanks very much for your help!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, glad that worked. Comments can be deleted at any time, so I've now posted this as an answer, as a guide to future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Try inserting:

```
optic_flow_movie.seek(0)
random_flow_movie.seek(0)
```

in between the two for loops, so each movie gets reset to its start frame before getting played again.

Comment: After installing the latest version of PsychoPy, I am running into the same problem. I have 10 trials with a random alternation of two videos. After two trials, the window freezes and no error is thrown.

Comment: The only way I have found to play the right number of movie repetition per condition was to add `optic_flow_movie.play()` before `optic_flow_movie.draw()`, and `random_flow_movie.play()` before `random_flow_movie.draw()`. By adding `.play()`, another problem arises, which is the videos that freeze for 2 seconds before being animated at each trial. I'd really appreciate help with this issue, I tried many things but I am still stuck... thanks :)