# Video freezes shortly before animation with MovieStim3 - PsychoPy

Tags: python, animation, mp4, psychopy

I have a sequence of 2 mp4 videos played 4 times (4 trials), with a fixation cross that appears before each animation as shown in the code below.
In order to load, play and draw the animations, I used MovieStim3 following [this demo] made by @richard. I used the functions .play and .draw to play and draw the movies.

The movies are played, however, at the beginning of the 3rd and 4th trial, the animation freezes for 3seconds before moving. This is really problematic because it is influencing badly the effect of the animation on my participants’ perception. Any advice would be very helpful. Thanks in advance :slight_smile:

```
# Load optic flow and random flow movies
optic_flow_movie    = visual.MovieStim3(win, 'optic_flow.mp4',loop= False)
random_flow_movie   = visual.MovieStim3(win, 'random_flow.mp4',loop= False)

for trialcount in range(nTrials):

    # We start the timer for each trial
    kb.clock.reset()  

    # Start with fixation cross 
    fixation.draw()
    win.flip()
    core.wait(2)

    # Play the video for 200 frames 

    optic_flow_movie.seek(0)
    random_flow_movie.seek(0)

    for Nframes in range(200):

        if conditions_rand[trialcount] == 1:
            optic_flow_movie.play()
            optic_flow_movie.draw()

        elif conditions_rand[trialcount] == 2:
            random_flow_movie.play()
            random_flow_movie.draw()


        fixation.draw()
        win.flip()
```

Comment: Is `.play()` even necessary here? i.e. `.draw()` should be sufficient. Not sure if that would make any difference but it would be worth trying it without that function call.

Comment: @MichaelMacAskill Only after adding the `.play()` that I managed to get all the animations played across the trials. When I used only `.draw()` it played only the first 2 animations then froze as reported here --> (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60532960/fail-to-play-sequence-of-mp4-videos-across-trials/61218416#61218416)

Comment: @MichaelMacAskill I also reported it long time ago on the forum of Psychopy but I didn't get an answer. Shall I use another module to read and play the video? is there a module that works well with Psychopy for this purpose?

Comment: MovieStim3 is generally best, but you could try dropping down to MovieStim2 or MovieStim just in case. More usefully, try different movie encodings, ensure the pixel dimensions are not larger than the size it will be played back at (to avoid unnecessary scaling and memory issues) and consider dropping the frame rate if applicable, eg if it is natively 60 Hz it will probably still look acceptable at 30 Hz.

Comment: @MichaelMacAskill Thx for your answer. Regarding the movie encodings and the pixel dimensions, I'd assume that it would have an impact on all the animations displayed across trials. However, the first two trials are perfectly displayed, and the freeze effect starts from the 3rd trial on. Also, without the function `play()`, only the first two trials are played.

Comment: @MichaelMacAskill I have tried `MovieStim` and I got the error `AttributeError: module 'pyglet.media' has no attribute 'ManagedSoundPlayer`. I've also tried `MovieStim2` and I got the error `TypeError: argument of type 'ModuleNotFoundError' is not iterable
`

Comment: @MichaelMacAskill Can I use Pyglet or Tkinter with PsychoPy only to upload and draw the videos? The functions for drawing and playing videos with PsychoPy are really not working and I have tried everything to my knowledge to make it work. It would be very helpful if I could find an alternative that also works with Psychopy

Comment: Can you give me the link to your forum post?  This has gone beyond my ability to give more useful suggestions, so will see if I can get the involvement of some of the key developers there.

Comment: @MichaelMacAskill Sure, here is the link https://discourse.psychopy.org/t/video-freezes-shortly-before-animation-with-moviestim3/14120. Thanks very much for your help!